# Conditional creation of row values based on another row

Tags: python, pandas

If the `days_to_last_follow_up` row value is equal to or more than `1825`, assign the value in the `survival` row as `0`. Otherwise, if it is less than `1825` or is `NA`, assign the `survival` row as `1`.

```
# Long-term survival >= 5 years (1825 days)
# Short-term survival < 5 years OR NA
def survival_status(col):
  if col.loc["days_to_last_follow_up"] >= 1825:
    return col.loc["survival"] == 0 # lts
  else:
    return col.loc["survival"] == 1 # non-lts

clinical.loc["survival"] = clinical.apply(survival_status, axis=0)
```

Input:

`clinical.iloc[0:4,0:4]`

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '53',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': '207.0'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '71',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': '2298.0'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '67',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': nan},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '60',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': '1731.0'}})
```

Expected output:

```
pd.DataFrame({'TCGA-2K-A9WE-01': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '53',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': '207.0',
  'survival': '1'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '71',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': '2298.0',
  'survival': '0'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '67',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': nan,
  'survival': '1'},
 'TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01': {'admin.batch_number': '398.45.0',
  'age': '60',
  'days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis': '0',
  'days_to_last_follow_up': '1731.0',
  'survival': '0'}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets use indexing with loc to select the row

```
df.loc['survival'] = (~df.loc['days_to_last_follow_up'].astype(float).ge(1825)).astype(int))
```

---

```
                                     TCGA-2K-A9WE-01 TCGA-2Z-A9J1-01 TCGA-2Z-A9J3-01 TCGA-2Z-A9J6-01
admin.batch_number                          398.45.0        398.45.0        398.45.0        398.45.0
age                                               53              71              67              60
days_to_initial_pathologic_diagnosis               0               0               0               0
days_to_last_follow_up                         207.0          2298.0             NaN          1731.0
survival                                           1               0               1               1
```